# Customizing Navbar Bootstrap MVC 4 (More Narrow Navbar & Brand Name Adjustment)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to customizing my navbar in two ways:

**1.**I want that the brand name will be in the same height of the tabs("Home", "About" etc'), i don't mind the different in size between them but i want that they will be in the same height.

**2.**I want to make the navbar more narrow than its now.

i also added a picture that demonstrates what i'm talking about (with numbers according to the sections)
[image]

How can i accomplish that?

Thank You

Comment: This has to do with padding, margin and line-height. You can use the Browser inspector tool to experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your brand name and menu items on the same hight you have to change a parameter called *padding*. When you wanna narrow the menu bar you can change te *min-height* parameter. These parameters can be changed in the *bootstrap.css* file.

**Equal menu items**

Change the padding in the following css classes:

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

**Narrow menubar**

Change the min-height in the following css class

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Usefull links to edit realtime css:
 - [Google chrome page inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)
 - [Firefox page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)
 - Firebug a universal page inspector --> getfirebug.com (cant post more then 2 links)

Comment: You have any idea how can i edit in "Page Inspector" of Google and keep my edit permanently ? 
i mean that Google page inspector will change my css ? its possible ?

Comment: @Ron yes you can! Its part of `Browser link`. There is a NuGet [`Web Essentials Package`](http://vswebessentials.com/) you can add to your project. More info about `Web Essentials` for visual studio: [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/12/03/browser-link-a-web-developer-s-new-best-friend.aspx)

Comment: Just the thing i was looking for, i'm new to CSS so this will help me a lot with my "Trial and error" hhh.
Thanks man ill check it!